# Как сделать автоматическую длину div?

Tags: html, css

Есть `<div>`. Как сделать так, чтобы когда допустим в нем было написано **"Вау!"** он становился *коротким*, а когда, например, **"Привет! Бла бла бла бла"** он был типа *длинным*?

Пример на картинках:

[image: Длинный]

[image: Короткий]

Вот мой код

```css
.message-from {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 11px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #1a1a1d;
    max-width: 295px; /*это длина как на первой картинке*/
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px solid #1a1a1d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 13px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: Beautiful, sans-serif;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-from">
   <h2>Вау!</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` Вам в помощь:

```css
.message-from {

    display: inline-block;
    
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 11px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #1a1a1d;
    max-width: 295px; /*это длина как на первой картинке*/
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px solid #1a1a1d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 13px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: Beautiful, sans-serif;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-from">
   <h2>Вау!</h2>
</div>
```